# Adding a "0" to the beginning of a 4 digit excel cell to make it a zip code.

Tags: excel

I have a row of numbers that are zip codes but because they all start with a zero (NJ) the zero gets dropped.  ie. 07749 only shows as 7749.  What formula can I write in another cell that will add a zero to the beginning of each of these? Thanks, Jerry.'Jeff

Comment: @pnuts, you're right! it would be the best solution!

Comment: Well, formatting might not always be the simplest solution, like in cases where you need lookup formulas and such.

Comment: Failed to mention these were formula cells

Comment: Now I'm trying to import it into MS streets and maps.  Even with the 0 showing, the program drops the zero. Any familiarity with this product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TEXT` like this with 5 zeros:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00000")
```